# What is the joint distribution of n identically distributed uniform distributions from $[0,1]$?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Given $U_1,U_2,...,U_n$ identical and independent uniform distributions of the form $U(0,1)$. Let $U_{(1)}<U_{(2)}<...<U_{(n)}$ be their order statistics, then what is their joint distribution $\left( U_{(1)},U_{(2)},...,U_{(n)}\right)$?

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Yes, I forgot to put what I thought it was on here. So the the PDF of $f_U(u)=1$ if $u\in[0,1]$ and $f_U(u)=0$ if $u\notin[0,1]$. Because each $U_i$ is independent, to find the join probability density function, I just multiply all of their PDFs:
\begin{align}
f_{U_1...U_n}(u_1,...,u_n)&=f_{U_1}(u_1)\cdot...\cdot f_{U_n}(u_n)\\
= &1 \quad \text{if} \quad u_1,u_2,...,u_n\in[0,1]\\
&0 \quad \text{if} \quad u_1,u_2,...,u_n\notin[0,1]
\end{align}
Although I am not sure how to say that because they are all multiplied, then if any of $u_i\notin [0,1]$ then $f_{U_1...U_n}(u_1,...,u_n)=0$.

Comment: If $U_1 < U_2$ they can't be independent...

Comment: i.i.d. random variables cannot be ordered in that fashion.

Comment: OP: Is what you mean to ask something about [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic)?  Or do you want to know the joint distribution of variables $V_1, V_2, \ldots, V_n$, where $V_k$ is the $k$th lowest entry out of the i.i.d. $\{U_i\}$?

Comment: @BrianTung, yes, I am still a novice so I wasn't sure what that meant or if it affected the joint distribution. I can reword the original question to help make it fit.

Comment: @BrianTung, I changed it does that work?

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or what you tried would be a big step forward!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit: OP has changed the question.

Let the random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n$ be i.i.d. continuous random variables with common pdf $f(x)$ and cdf $F(x)$.  Denote $Y_i = X_{(i)}$, where $X_{(i)}$ represents the $i$th ordered statistic. The joint pdf of $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
f_{\mathbf{Y}}(y_1, \ldots, y_n) = \begin{cases}
n! \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(y_i), & \text{ if } - \infty < y_1 \leq \ldots \leq y_n < \infty\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

The multiplier $n!$ occurs because we can arrange the $y_1, \ldots y_n$ in $n!$ ways and the pdf for any such arrangement is the product $\prod_{i=1}^{n} f(y_i)$ via the iid assumption.

For the uniform distribution, $f(u) = 1$, $0 < u < 1$, hence $\prod_{i=1}^{n} f(y_i) = 1$.  The joint pdf is thus

\begin{equation*}
f_{\mathbf{Y}}(y_1, \ldots, y_n) = \begin{cases}
n!, & \text{ if } 0 < y_1 \leq \ldots \leq y_n < 1\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Do you mean we can rearrange the $y_1,...,y_n$ in $n!$ ways, or am I not understanding something? What if some of the $y_i$'s were equal?

Comment: $n!$ ways - I have fixed the typo.  Since $f(x)$ is continuous, $P(Y_i = Y_j)=0$ for $i \neq j$.

Comment: Normal distribution?

Comment: @NapD.Lover, edited, thank you.

Comment: @Jackson Why does the $n!$ come into play? If there is an order statistic, then isn't there only one way it can be configured?

Comment: @Tasangares - it is true that the order statistics $y_1, \ldots, y_n$ can only be in one order.  However, we may observe $y_1$ `first', 'second', 'third', etc., leaving only $n-1$ potential spots to observe $y_2$, leaving only $n-2$ spots to observe $y_3$ and so on.  In other words, the smallest order statistic could be observed in any of the $n$ observations, $X_1$, $X_2$, and so on.

Comment: @Jackson, do you have any reference to this that I can read about? I believe you but I am still a bit confused on this counting problem.

Comment: See the excellent Probability and Statistical Inference by Nitis Mukhopadhyay. Specifically, pg. 182. See the downloadable pdf for the exact reference: https://www.zuj.edu.jo/download/probability-and-statistical-inference-nitis-mukhopadhyay-pdf/